# jsp servlet Mysql database connectivity error

Tags: mysql, jsp, servlets

I have main page index.jsp. from jsp page requset has been sent to database.But database connection is not happening.Its not giving any error and its giving blank page.Even I have added mysql connector.jar to library file.am using tomcatserver. Can anybody please help me what is the problem.Here is the complete code

```
    disply.java


public class MyDb {
    Connection con;
    public Connection getcon()  { 
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/studentinfo", "root", "adminuser");

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MyDb.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MyDb.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return con;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to assign the Connection Object to the connection returned from the DriverManager

```
 Connection con = null;
 ....
 con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql......
```

Comment: at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)  am gettin this error I have given that

Comment: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1333) at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)
 at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
 at display.processRequest(display.java:41)
 at display.doPost(display.java:85)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)

Comment: This exception means that the jdbc driver (jar file usualy named for mySql as mysql-connector-java-5.1.32-bin.jar for jdbc version 5.1) was not found by your application. If you are using an IDE include the jdbc file to the libraries of your project, or add the jdbc under WEB-INF/lib folder of your project

Comment: jdbc.jar and mysql.connector.jar libraries already  i have added but still its giving error

Comment: jdbc.jar and mysql.connector.jar is the same thing. Try only one of the two

Comment: I have removed jdbc.jar .But still giving this error    java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Thanku  MaVRoSCy.Data has been retrieved